# Kotlin Coroutines remove exception handler from scope

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

In code below I am fetching some data. If error/exception was thrown I want the exception handler to catch it. Once done with fetching, I am posting the result using `LiveData` to whoever is observing.

What I am trying to achieve is that the exception handler to finish its job once I post the result. Which means, if the observer handling the result also throws an exception, I don't want the coroutine exception handler to catch it (Which is the case in code below).

```
fun loadPrerequisites(resultObserver: MutableLiveData<PrerequisiteDataHolder?>) {

    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        resultObserver.postValue(null)
    }

    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler) {
        val deferredCreationScheme = async {
            fetchCreationScheme()
        }

        val creationScheme = deferredCreationScheme.await()

        //TODO remove exception handler at this stage?

        resultObserver.postValue(PrerequisiteDataHolder(creationScheme))
    }
}
```

Is there a way to remove the exception handler before posting the result to the LiveData? Or must I introduce a new scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the purpose of the coroutine exception handler. It is the coroutine equivalent of `uncaughtExceptionExceptionHandler` in Java and its purpose is to inform you of an exception that has already broken its coroutine. You seem to want to use it to implement business logic-level exception handling.

The coroutine exception handler is not a replacement for the try-catch block, and the latter is what you should use in your case.

I think you don't need `async` in your code in the first place, I believe this is all you really need:

```
scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    resultObserver.postValue(
            try {
                PrerequisiteDataHolder(fetchCreationScheme())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                null
            }
    )
}
```

I typically use a helper function for code like this:

```
inline fun <T> tryOrNull(block: () -> T) = try {
    block()
} catch (t: Throwable) {
    null
}
```

Then your code becomes

```
scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    tryOrNull { PrerequisiteDataHolder(fetchCreationScheme()) }
    .also { resultObserver.postValue(it) }
}
```

Comment: So the solution in this case is just wrapping the await call with a try catch. handle the error in catch part and keep the exception handler for logging since async re-throws the exception?

Comment: You should prevent the `async` task itself from failing by catching it inside.

Comment: Ok cool understood! But if plan to have more that one async in parallel then i do need to wrap all of the `await` and not try catch each async

Comment: If you have multiple async calls, they should all be inside a `coroutineScope { ... }` and then you should wrap the whole `coroutineScope` in a try-catch.